# What should a candidate ask in an informal phone call to Hiring Person in Department

Tags: job, academic-life

Many positions, especially in UK, have an email or phone number for the Head of Department.
What should a candidate ask in these informal phone calls about academic posts?

Example:
For informal enquiries: please contact Professor --------------- on ------@---.ac.uk

Comment: To the head of department, ask only what is essential.

Comment: In the U.S., a departmental administrator will actually be the person reading many of the emails officially addressed to the department chair... And, in the U.S., certainly do not _phone_, but only email.

Answer (score 4):

#### At applicant stage

Avoid asking anything unless it is absolutely necessary. If you do have something to ask, keep it short and clear. It is likely that the head of the department is very busy and there are a fair number of applications to process each year.

#### At candidate stage

Is the head of department your main point of contact for hiring? If they are, then I would freely ask them everything you are concerned about (except, obviously, things you can find online). They are trying to hire you, so they will want to answer your questions. At the candidate (rather than applicant) stage, generally you are the "guest of honor", so to speak, and they are the hosts.

However, usually there is a main point of contact aside from the head of department, e.g., someone in your research area who wanted to hire you. (I'm not familiar with the UK.) If so, then it seems prudent to direct questions there first.

Comment: It is entirely acceptable to submit an application without contacting the head of department, if you don't have any particular questions.

Comment: @avid Yes, good addition. I assumed the OP was at candidate stage.

Comment: The text the OP quotes is found in most UK job adverts, see e.g. https://www.jobs.ac.uk/job/BZK348/lecturer

Comment: Thank you all for your answers so far. Just to clarify, this is at the applicant stage.

Comment: @mcwkeaveney Good to know. Updated.

Comment: Don't be a pest. Especially at the applicant phase. And use restraint until you have an offer in hand. The head is pretty busy.

Comment: They are trying to find the best candidate and the selection process is a two way street. They are as much trying to see if you are the best fit for them and also demonstrate to you why they are the place for you to want to work.